# How to get request url and request body when use wp_router_generate_routes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to use php and wordpress, see [this article](https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/35542/wordpress-creating-new-routes-custom-urls-with-wp-router) to add route to wordpress, the code like:

```
add_action( 'wp_router_generate_routes', 'bl_add_routes', 20 );

function bl_add_routes( $router ) { 
    $route_args = array(
                        'path' => '^new-demo-route',
                        'page_callback' => 'my_callback'
                );

    $router->add_route( 'demo-route-id', $route_args );
}

function my_callback( ) {
    return "Congrats! Your demo callback is fully functional. Now make it do something fancy";
}
```

If in client, I use `curl my-domain/new-demo-route?param_key=param_value -d "{ctn: 'here is body'}"`

in `my_callback`, how to get request url and request body

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

get request url:

```
$this_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"
```

get request body(only work for post request)

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```